# React/Webpack Css imports from node_modules are not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am using these three css imports from various packages:

```js
// want to do import 'path/to/css.css'
import slickCss from "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"
import slickCssTheme from "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css"
import leafcss from 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

console.log(`Slick Css: `, slickCss)
console.log(`Slick Theme Css: `, slickCssTheme)
console.log(`leaf css: `, leafcss)
```

If I log those out they are all empty objects:

```
Slick Css:  {}
Slick Theme Css:  {}
leaf css:  {}
```

I assume that something is going wrong with how I am using the loader for webpack. For the most part that I can see everything else is working as far as the react bundle goes. For now I will attach my webpack to not over complicate things. If there is no problem with the webpack I will start adding the necessary files. I tried the alias and still got the same result.

```js
var path = require(`path`)

module.exports = {
  mode: `development`,
  entry: `./scripts/inject.js`,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `dist`),
    filename: `bundle.js`,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [`.html`, `.js`, `.json`, `.scss`, `.css`],
    alias: {
      leafModule: __dirname + `/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css`,
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: `file-loader`,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: `file-loader`,
            options: {
              name: `[name].[ext]`,
              outputPath: `fonts/`,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [`style-loader`, `css-loader`],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use:  {
          loader: `babel-loader`,
          options: {
            presets: [`@babel/preset-env`],
          },
        }, 
      },  
    ],
  }, 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your setup is able to collect your style properly. From my point of view, you can use `mini-css-extract-plugin` to help you collect your css. Here is additional code you may add to your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
 // ...
 modules: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,            
        },
        {
          loader: `css-loader`,
          options: {
            // Enable css as module so we can import
            modules: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
 },

 plugins: [
  // ...
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].css',
    chunkFilename: '[id].css',
  }),
 ]
}
```

However, keep in mind that if you switch css to module, it won't inject automatically anymore since each class name will be renamed so you have to import and add manually like:

```js
import css from "path/to/css";

<div classSName={css.headerClass} />
```

As a result of that, you will have trouble with 3rd packages which have css files to import as your case.

Comment: Still an empty object after adding the `modules: true`

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo?

Comment: see the `Inject script` info in the readme to see what I'm doing. Ignore the CRA stuff for now. https://github.com/tbaustin/react-leaflet-locator

Comment: I looked inside the bundle and it references ./node_modules which I don't think exist in the folder that gets created only in the root.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your case. To sum up, it looks like with your setup doesn't collect any css so I suggest to use `mini-css-extract-plugin` instead.

Comment: Is there a better way I could set this up?

Comment: Also I did exactly what you said and it still doesn't work. I was able to do something like: 
```
const leafStyles = Object.keys(leafcss).reduce((acc, cur) => {
   return `${acc} ${leafcss[cur]}`
  }, ``)
```

Then add `leafStyles` to the `className` and I can see them in the inspector but it doesn't apply the styles.

Comment: Also I'm not really wanting to do `import variable from 'path/to/css'` I'm wanting to just do `import 'path/to/css'`

Comment: Not sure what you want for now. If you're keen to import like this `import 'path/to/css'` which means you have to switch option `modules` back to false. Actually, we can configure like `create-react-app` does is to support both css module + normal css

Comment: One more thing, in order to save your time as develop I think you should use `html-webpack-plugin` to create your `index.html` file which webpack will inject the bundle into it, and utilize `webpack-server` as your server which has live reload that helps you update your app straight away as your made changes on your code

Comment: You mind giving an example of all that? If I just want to do the `import 'path/to/css'` I think it's what i need to do for those react modules anyway. I was just trying to get a console to see what was going on. I never wanted an actual var.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223827/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-taylor-austin).